# Compare time slots in python

Tags: python, datetime

I have the following list of time slots(start_date, end_date), sorted by start date:

```
slots = [(datetime.datetime(2017, 10, 2, 6, 0), datetime.datetime(2017, 10, 2, 17, 40)), 
(datetime.datetime(2017, 10, 2, 10, 35), datetime.datetime(2017, 10, 2, 16, 25)), 
(datetime.datetime(2017, 10, 2, 11, 0), datetime.datetime(2017, 10, 2, 12, 0)), 
(datetime.datetime(2017, 10, 2, 12, 0), datetime.datetime(2017, 10, 2, 13, 0)), 
(datetime.datetime(2017, 10, 2, 15, 0), datetime.datetime(2017, 10, 2, 16, 0)),
(datetime.datetime(2017, 10, 2, 18, 0), datetime.datetime(2017, 10, 2, 19, 0))]
```

I would like to remove all timeslots with a start date and an end date included in another timeslot present this list.

So here, for example, the end result should be:

```
slots = [(datetime.datetime(2017, 10, 2, 6, 0), datetime.datetime(2017, 10, 2, 17, 40)),
(datetime.datetime(2017, 10, 2, 18, 0), datetime.datetime(2017, 10, 2, 19, 0))]
```

I have tried to reduce it with the following function, but it doesn't work:

```
reduce(slots_removal, slots)

def slots_removal(a, b):
    if a[1] > b[1]:
        del b
```

This produces:

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'"
```

Comment: Is your input always sorted? What about partial overlaps (start is before end of a previous entry, but end is after)?

Comment: Hi @MartijnPieters, yes I sort the input to make it easier to filter afterwards using `slots = sorted(current_schedule, key = lambda x: x[0])`

So start can be before end of a previous entry and end after, but it shouldn't impact the result, no ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your input is always sorted, you could just use a generator function:

```
import datetime

def reduced(timeseries):
    prev = datetime.datetime.min
    for start, end in timeseries:
        if end > prev:
            prev = end
            yield start, end
```

This only yields `(start, end)` tuples if `end` is later than the previousy yielded tuple.

Demo:

```
>>> list(reduced(slots))
[(datetime.datetime(2017, 10, 2, 6, 0), datetime.datetime(2017, 10, 2, 17, 40)), (datetime.datetime(2017, 10, 2, 18, 0), datetime.datetime(2017, 10, 2, 19, 0))]
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(_)
[(datetime.datetime(2017, 10, 2, 6, 0),
  datetime.datetime(2017, 10, 2, 17, 40)),
 (datetime.datetime(2017, 10, 2, 18, 0),
  datetime.datetime(2017, 10, 2, 19, 0))]
```

You can't use `reduce()`; that function produces a *single result* from an input sequence. The output of the function becomes the input for the next call (together with the next element); because your function doesn't explicitl return anything, `None` is returned instead and used as input for the next call.

Comment: Thanks a million, it works great!! And thanks for the explanation regarding the reduce() function!